# Clock Conversion for RTL Verilog (FPGA) Synthesizable Code

Tags: verilog, fpga, clock, register-transfer-level

Converting 12 MHz system clock signal on FPGA to 1 MHz Signal output at a 50% duty cycle.

I understand that I need to divide by 2 @ 50/50 duty cycle to get 6 MHz, and then divide by 2 again to get to 3 MHz, and then divide by 3 to get to 1 MHz. Is this the correct method?

Also, how would I implement this in RTL Verilog code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct method?

No. First, operating on clocks in logic is often difficult to route appropriately, especially in multiple stages. Second, it is especially difficult to divide a clock by 3 and get a 50% duty cycle without either negative-edge or DDR flip-flops, both of which are often unavailable in FPGA fabric.

The correct method is to use your FPGA's clocking resources. Most modern FPGAs will have one or more onboard DLLs or PLLs which can be used to manage clock signals.

On Xilinx parts, these resources are known as the DCM, PLL, and/or MMCM, and can be instantiated using the ClockGen IP core.

On Altera/Intel parts, these resources can be configured through the PLL and other megafunctions.

On Lattice parts, these resources are known as the sysCLOCK PLL, and can be configured using IPexpress.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I understand that there is MMCM and the clocking wizard on this fpga. But currently, i'm doing this all on modelSim/QuestaSim, there are other signals that I am writing logic for that are all dependent on this 1 MHz Clock. So what do you propose for this situation?

Comment: @tnet You use the MMCM. (Or let the clocking wizard use it for you.) 12 MHz clock goes in, 1 MHz clock comes out. No muss, no fuss.

Comment: @tnet Just as a general note, most IP blocks provided by FPGA vendors (and others) will allow you to build a simulation model of the block for running simulations in tools like ModelSim, just be sure you build the simulation model as well when configuring the IP in whichever vendors tools.